# Random 404 using IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

What would cause IIS to return a 404, only sometimes? If I hit a 404 on a page, I can simply hit refresh and it will come up. It's reproducible. I've used fiddler to see what's going on and I don't see anything off. I've setup IIS tracing but again, I don't see what exactly the issue would be, the file exists and the 404 only occurs sometimes. By sometimes I mean if I navigated to a page and got a 404 I could refresh and it would come up but other times I could navigate to that page and it would not 404. It isn't limited to any one page or condition.

What other things can I try to determine what the issue is?

Comment: If you navigate to the page(s) using a new "private browsing" window (i.e., no cookies etc.), does the 404 always occur? Also, what modules, wildcard mappings, and handlers are configured in IIS?

Comment: @Justin yes it doesn't matter if it's in private browsing.

Comment: I'm not clear on your answer. Does the 404 _always_ occur on the *first* visit in a *new* private browsing session, or is it still random?

Comment: It doesnt matter if it's private browsing or not, it's always random.

Comment: Then you need to look at the modules, wildcard mappings, handlers, and filters that are configured in IIS and/or the Web.config. Disable them and use process of elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've run Fiddler and you see the request arrive at the server and you see a 404, then this doesn't sound like a web farm problem.

You might want to try [SysInternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what's going on underneath.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for this is that you have a web farm with several machines, on one machine the pages are missing.

Therefore, each time you randomly use the machine with the missing pages you get a 404.

Comment: Or rather a "web farm" in the Microsoft nomenclature. A "cluster" is usually just failover in Microsoft-speak, not load balancing.

Comment: There is no web farm or cluster or load balancing

Answer (score 1):

I've had this similar issue and I traced it back to changing this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

to:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
```

Obviously, analysis will need to be done to make sure that this doesn't affect your application in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I have only has this when an MVC application because for certain situations my routes were not correct. Clicking would produce the 404 but F5(refresh) would show the webpage correctly. You don't mention mvc but thought it worth throwing this in.