# My website randomly returns 404 sometimes. How do I stop this?

Tags: asp.net

I have a job application website I built and it's been working great for the year or so. Recently, and this is a new thing that's happening, The website well return 404. Now the default home page is still there. And the sql stuff is still stable too.

I've noticed that it can also be browser dependent. So sometimes it returns 404 to google chrome, but not Firefox or IE. Or some combination of that.

This will happen, the page returning 404, often randomly throughout the day, and last for several minutes, then it well continue normally.

The webpage is an aspx.net webpage with some vb.net stuff behind running the latest version of .net. The website's run off of IIS.

I'm fairly certain nothing in my code, or my sql calls would prompt this behaviour. We have no scheduled tasks running related to the website, so i'm pretty stumped.What would casue this behaviour of oft-random 404 errors?

[Edit]

A quick synopsis:

-The 404 is a regular 404, without a subscript attached to it

-It's happening to random people throughout the office

-It's happening at random times

-It's only affecting certain browsers, but all browsers are effected at some point

-It doesn't appear to be happening externally

-There is nothing i've tried that can reproduce this error.

Comment: What is the 404 [SubStatus](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758476%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) returned?

Comment: Have you checked the log files? Maybe posting the entries from that would help further. "C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles"

Comment: I don't know what the substatus is. How do I return that value? I don't have access to the log files, but I can get that shortly.

Comment: Well the link Blachshma posted shows how to get the sub status. But basically you'll probably need access to the logs. Also, Im not sure whether the response contains this information in the header. Have a look at your error handling and see if theres extended info in the exception (headers etc.)

Comment: @Lenigod: This might be more relevant. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I've taken a look at the log files in the system32\logfiles directory. None of the 404 errors are coming with a subset. In other words the logged errors all end in 404 - NotFound - and that's it.

Comment: Hmm, well if its only started happening recently then I'd look into recent win updates, IIS config, AppPool changes among other things. What has changed on the server? Also, look at whats changed in your source history from when the problem started. Web farms may also be a source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438250/random-404-using-iis

Comment: What IIS version/OS are you using? There may be some diagnostics you can use to catch more information. http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I'll look at that Bic. Also, if might be worth noting that when this 404 stuff happens, a lot of times it's not for everybody. Some people in the same department I'm in will be able to reach it, while others like me still cant. And vice versa. This error isn't effecting everyone at the same time on every browser. Nor have I found a way to reproduce the error. I'm still very distraught about it all.

Comment: @Lenigod: can you add all relevant versions (IIS, Webserver OS etc.) to your update. There may be version specific solutions and known issues.

Comment: @Lenigod:Also, please add all information about the infrastructure that you can. Is it a webfarm, are there proxies and other network related systems involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've rebooted our server that hold the application system on it. It seems to have solved the issue so far. If it happens again and we solve it differently, I'll be sure to come back and update this answer.

Comment: This was the latest IIS version running on server 2008, which was running an aspx page that was getting the 404s. Different websites were not experiencing the same problem, so it was specific to this application pool.